# What is the locus of points in a plane equidistant from a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, locus

I was working on an exam review packet for high school and I saw a question about locuses of points equidistant from a circle and lying on a given line. My confusion is that the answer key is inconsistent with the solutions the teacher put online. Also, I emailed the teacher, and I'm still waiting on his take. While I'm waiting, may I get a few suggestions?

Comment: Please provide more context. What is the answer given? What is the teacher's solution?

Comment: You need to show us what you're confused about.

Comment: `the answer key is inconsistent with the solutions the teacher put online` If you have *two* solutions already, you should post them and point out where the confusion lies.

Comment: The problem is that there is a circle with a diameter of 10, and a given line. The locus is 8 away from the circle and has to lie on the line. Since there is no word on where the line lies, there are multiple answers. The answer key said that there was 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 points, which I (and my dad, we were studying together), were confused by until we came up with a theory that said that the points can go inside through the circle (is that correct?), but the solutions of this problem and other problems concerning locusts said it was 0, 1, or 2 points and the work was not helping me.

Comment: Here is a link if you guys want to see what I mean by ‘the work is not helping’. [link] (http:/i.imgur.com/YpSmN3h.jpg)

Comment: Your original post did not mention the line at all.  How can anyone help you without that?  "Equidistant from"  needs two things to be equidistant from.  I looked at the link and it is a rough sketch without any explanation.  Voting to close.

Comment: While editing the question, you should also have put the essential information there about the diameter, the distance of the locus, and who said the possible answers were 0,1,2 vs. 0,1,2,3,4; you can also insert a link to your picture. The comments are not the place to reveal _any_ of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without additional constraint the locus of points equidistant (at distance d) from a circle (of radius r) is the union of two circles of radius $r\pm d$.

So you have to distinguish for cases:

- $d>r$ in this case there is only one circle.
- $d=r$ there is one circle and a point.
- $d<r$ there are two circles.

Now if you add the constraint that the points also belong to a line, then you have to look whether the line passes through the common center, is tangent or crosses the various circles involved, or is too far to have intersection points.

When you put all this together, you will find $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ possible points of intersection.

Comment: But if the diameter of the circle is $10,$ then $r = 5$ (the radius is half the diameter), and then if $d=8$ we have only one circle, so $0, 1, 2$ is the correct answer in that case.

Comment: @DavidK Yes sure, I did not detailed which were the possible values for all the cases. I proposed a methodology to exhausts all the cases and said that over all the possibles cases only the values 0,1,2,3,4 can be reached, but for a single case only a subset of these numbers is valid.

Comment: Part of the question seemed to concern whether the OP's particular case could have 4 points or could only have at most 2--the teacher and the answer key had given conflicting answers. So the particular application to this particular case seems relevant.